# AngularJs templaturl error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

```
          when('/contact', {

              templateUrl: './Contact.html',
              controller: 'ContactController'
          }).
          otherwise(
            {
              redirectTo: '/home'
          });
```

I am having templateurl like this. When I try to execute, My template url is not working. I have attached link to my application [Angular TemplateURL](https://github.com/KarthikRavichandrann/simpleangularjs) . Please help me on how to fix the issuse.

Comment: What error you are getting while accessing your route?

Comment: Based upon the project structure from your github link, should not the templateUrl be pages/Contact.html ?

Comment: set base href meta tag then use /

Answer (score 0):

Is it showing a 404 error? If yes, then check the path that it tried for finding your partials. Make sure that the path you have mentioned is correct. It is relative to the index. It should be pages/'pagename'.html

```
when('/contact', {

          templateUrl: 'pages/Contact.html',
          controller: 'ContactController'
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should first understand how relative path works. So, here it follows:

> `/` means the root of the current drive
>
> `./` means the current directory
>
> `../` means the parent of the current directory.

As you have used :`templateUrl: './Contact.html',` it will try to look into the current directory.

So you have to change the path of your template URL's like this:

```
 when('/contact', {

              templateUrl: './pages/Contact.html',
              controller: 'ContactController'
          }).
          otherwise(
            {
              redirectTo: '/home'
          });
```